# aws-sdk-rails config error: Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, amazon-ses

I am trying to use ActionMailer in Rails 6 with the aws-sdk-rails gem, but receive a Missing Region error. I am a little unsure about how the configurations get used. My credentials are in `credentials.yaml.enc`, but my region is configured in the environment file with  `Aws::Rails.add_action_mailer_delivery_method(:ses, region: 'eu-west-2')` The region however does not seem to be picked up there when I trigger my mailer within the controller `PaymentRequestMailer.request_payment_email.deliver_now` even after server restart.

I'd appreciate some advice on how to track down the issue.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was adding the delivery method correctly, but only after I had already added it with `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses`. I have removed that and it appears to now be working.